# Is it possible to monkey-patch a built-in class in Jython?

Tags: jython, monkeypatching, built-in, forbiddenfruit

After discovering [forbidden fruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit), a CPython package that made me stare in shear horror as I observed unholy desecration of Python's sacred built-in classes, I was wondering if such a thing could be/has been done in Jython too?

For instance, do something along the lines of:

```py
>>> from evil import desecrate
>>> unleash_hell = lambda x: "Madness"
>>> descrate(int, "__str__", unleash_hell)
>>> print(int(10))
Madness
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this with success:

```
>>> def sayHello(self):
...   print 'hello'
... 
>>> import java.lang.String as String
>>> String.sayHello = sayHello
>>> String().sayHello()
hello
```

Comment: Interesting :-) Unfortunately, this seems to only apply to the underlying java types as `int.hello = lambda: "hello"` produces `TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in extension type 'int'`